# JavaScript scope online accounts - OnlineAccountClient error

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, scopes

I'm trying to run a Unity JavaScript scope which uses online accounts on Ubuntu 15.10 on the Unity Scopes Tool, but I get an error when using the OnlineAccountClient class.

I followed the [Online Accounts Guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/platform/guides/online-accounts-developer-guide/) - added the account policy group, added the app.application and app.service files, and updated manifest.json according to the examples.

I'm using the facebook account as well, so the configuration is basically the same, let me know if I need to provide it..

Couldn't find any examples how to use the OnlineAccountClient class, but judging by the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~webapps/unity-js-scopes/trunk/view/head:/src/bindings/src/online-account-client.h), it seems I have to pass 3 parameters.

So, I tried to use it in my scope's search function like this:

```
var account = new scopes.lib.OnlineAccountClient('com.ubuntu.developer.me.untitled_untitled', 'ubuntu.com.developer.me.untitled_untitled', 'facebook')
```

The first and second argument is the service type from app.service and service id from app.application. Untitled is the default scope name, just testing now so I didn't change it.

But when I run the scope I get the following error:

```
/home/user/Scopes/build-untitled-Desktop_2-Default/src/untitled.username_untitled.js:60
    var account = new scopes.lib.OnlineAccountClient('com.ubuntu.developer.me.untitled_untitled', 'ubuntu.com.developer.me.untitled_untitled', 'facebook');
                  ^
Error: bad_weak_ptr
    at Error (native)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/user/Scopes/build-untitled-Desktop_2-Default/src/untitled.username_untitled.js:60:51)
```

Any ideas why am I getting this error and how to fix it?
Is this even the correct way to use online accounts in js scopes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for this, this is indeed a bug, I filed:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-js-scopes/+bug/1549477

and pushed a merge request for a fix, thank you for this,

the fix will be out & released in the next few days,

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.

While going through the code, **I did not find any factory/init/static method** for creating an OnlineAccountClient object. In the tests http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity-scopes-api/trunk/view/head:/test/gtest/scopes/OnlineAccountClient/OnlineAccountClient_test.cpp a **shared_ptr** is already being created before calling the OnlineAccountClient constructor, which is needed for the shared_from_this() method call done by this constructor.

Thus: I could be wrong or leaving something out, but are we lacking this kind of factory for node.js access? Does a workaround (like node.js addon for your project) make sense? E.g.: http://jltrem.com/blog/2013/02/06/simple-example-node-js-addon-to-glue-c-to-javascript/ 
Regards,
tecsurf